# Australian with P2 license hiring car in Spain

Tags: car-rentals, spain, australian-citizens, driving-licenses

I'm looking to hire a car in Spain. I called Avis there and they said you can't drive in Spain with an Australian provisional license but the guy on the phone wasn't really sure what it is and probably thought it was like a learner's license. You can get an IDP (International Driver's Permit) if you have an Australian provisional license does anyone know if it is legal to drive with an IDP + P2 license in Spain? And if so how can I convince the car hire place that it is the equivalent of a full license?

Answer (score 1):

The DGT states in [its website](https://sede.dgt.gob.es/es/tramites-y-multas/permiso-de-conduccion/canje-de-permisos/espana.shtml) that you can drive in Spain if you carry an official translation to Spanish of your license. Check if Australia qualifies for the other possibilities in the website.

However, I'm not sure about provisional licenses. In Spain new drivers or people renewing licenses get a provisional authorization to drive (which is just a DIN-A4 sheet of paper) that is only valid for Spain. A full license (a credit-card like license, with all the usual security elements) is required to drive abroad.

Answer (score 0):

Learner drivers in Spain must sit beside a professional instructor when in control of a vehicle and, if not, they cannot drive. Therefore, Spain does not have an equivalent to a provisional drivers license.

You will have to have an IDP, although I don't know whether you can obtain one with a provisional license.